# Take action when entire React dom tree has loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I fire an action when the entire React DOM tree has loaded? As in knowing when siblings of a child have loaded. I believe `componentDidUpdate` of a container component is only supposed to fire when it's fully rendered (as in its child components have rendered), but I'm finding that is not the case.

For example:

```
class ParentContainer extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // all of the children should be rendered by now?
    const { section } = this.props
    const scrollToEl = document.getElementById(section)
    if (scrollToEl) {
       scrollToEl.scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SiblingWithChildren1 />
        <SiblingWithChildren2 />
        <Child1>
          <Child2>
            array.map(comp => 
              <Section id={comp.id} />
            )
          </Child2>
        </Child1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In this case the document begins to scroll to the element that might match a `Section` id.

But, the scroll comes up short because everything hasn't fully rendered in the DOM yet, even if only by milliseconds. If the `SiblingWithChildren` components have not fully loaded it throws off the height of the document.

Using a `setTimeout` seems brittle.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` fires where it is updated, `componentDidMount` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @nzajt `componentDidMount` would fire even before `componentDidUpdate`, so that would be even less helpful. Need to wait until all of the child components have rendered.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` if for some reason you don't like timeout?

Comment: @slotdp02 `componentDidUpdate` is not called after `componentDidMount`. If you want to call something on the initial load you need to do it in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Do you have async code and the like? Because with basic static elements, the root component's `componentDidMount()` fires last, after all children: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2v5nr933z

Comment: I trust that you guys are correct. I guess that `componentDidMount` is even too soon because although in my case the component has mounted, it hasn't fully rendered in the browsers DOM (by a few milliseconds) which causes an issue.

Comment: @ChrisG yes I have asynchronous work going on but the component does not render until that work is finished.

Comment: Are you positive about that? The component is usually rendered when it is first mounted, then `componentDidMount()` is called, which starts some async process, and when that finishes, state is changed and the component is re-rendered. If your component does something different, you need to add it to your question, because that is crucial to answering it.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidUpdate` only fires on updates.

On the initial load you need `componentDidMount`.

The docs for a React Component life cycle are here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html.

Comment: `componentDidMount` would fire even before `componentDidUpdate`, so that would be even less helpful. Need to wait until all of the child components have rendered

Comment: When it initially loads `componentDidUpdate` is not called.

Comment: I wanted to show you this in action. The last react component to load is the parent. https://codepen.io/nzajt_1470347028/pen/RvYwJx.